# Android: activity does not work after backing from a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

i have an activity like WelcomeActivity and a fragment like GuideFragment.
i have a button in WelcomeActivity which cause a navigation to GuideFragment. Also i have a button in GuideFragment which navigates back to the  WelcomeActivity.
For first time it goes to GuideFragment by clicking on the button and cames back to WelcomeActivity  by pressing btn_back. Hwever after coming back to activity, the  button does not work any more.
whats wrong with my code?
activity clas:

```
 public class WelcomeActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
GuideFragment guideFragment = new GuideFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    guideFragment = new GuideFragment();
}
public void onGuideClick(View view)
{
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, guideFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

and fragment class:

```
 public class GuideFragment extends Fragment
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.guideFrag);
    // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    // inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guide, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            getActivity().getFragmentManager ().popBackStack();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `fragmentManager.popBackStack();` from `onGuideClick(View view)`. Also the transaction should not be a member field.

```
public void onGuideClick(View view) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, guideFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

You also initiate the GuideFragment twice, once is enough.

Comment: The application stops from working and I get an error in logcat like this:
"Could not execute method of the activity"

Comment: Is it related to this problem? Otherwise please create a new question and include the logcat. This to not bloat the question and confuse readers.

Comment: Your answer was fine. When I use popBackStack and come back to activity, fragmentTransaction is null. So I set it in onGuideClick method.

Answer (score 0):

I changed WelcomeActivity like this:

```
 public class WelcomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
}

public void onGuideClick(View view)
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    GuideFragment guideFragment = new GuideFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, guideFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}